# (J)Ruby: different results of [].pack('m') using Jruby or Ruby

Tags: ruby, jruby, base64, pack

I want to encode a jpeg image to base64.
Googling, i have this code:

```
name = 'path_to_file'
b64 = [open(name).read].pack('m')
puts b64.size
```

If this code its executed with Jruby1.5.1 (come with netbeans), the result of the size(with my image) its 3518, but if its executed with ruby 1.8.7, the size its 90.
Passing to an html file, only the encoded with JRuby works.

Someone know the reason of this?
Thanks in advance.
Notes: Running in Windows, and i hasn't touched the ruby1.8.7 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has different behaviour depending upon whether you open the file in binary mode or not; change that line to:

```
b64 = [open(name, 'rb').read].pack('m')
```

Comment: Yeah, thats the corrects answer, apparently Jruby automagically detect if the file its binary or text.

Comment: You should *always* pass `b` or `t`. It doesn't make a difference on most operating systems, but it *does* on Windows, and you can save yourself (and your Windows users) a bunch of trouble by simply just explicitly declaring whether you expect the file to be binary or text. (The difference is that for text files, Windows does newline conversion on its own, before the content is even passed to the program.)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @jorg-w-mittag, I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same sizes in jruby 1.5.1 RVM on Linux and Ruby 1.8.7 on Linux.  I suspect that you are only encoding the path for some reason.  Try printing `open(name).read` and assure your file is being opened and read successfully.  I do not think that it is.

```
jruby-1.5.1 :001 >  [open("test.jpg").read].pack('m').size
 => 3274 

ruby-1.8.7-p302 :003 > [open("test.jpg").read].pack('m').size
 => 3274
```